# How to set up notepad ++ for asking to save / cancel modifications on application closure

Tags: notepad++

I prefer to do not have unsaved modifications when notepad ++ is closed.
How can I set up the application in order it ask for save / cancel modifications when the program is closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to
`Settings` --> `Preferences` --> `Backup`, and remove “**Enable session snapshot and periodic backup**”

Then it will ask you to save or not to save when closing the program.